# Is there a way to use 'query' and 'forloop' together in Djang templates?

Tags: html, django, sqlite, templates

```
{% for game in game_query %}
{% for i in game.data.participantIdentities %}
{% if i.player.summonerName == summoners_result.name %}
{% if i.participantId == game.participants.forloop.counter0.participantId %}
{% if game.participants.forloop.counter0.stats.win == true%}
win
{% else %}
false
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The game_query is json data with game data.

The summoners_result.name is a user nickname.

The problem is the game.participants.forloop.counter0.participantId (Nothing is printed out)

Is there a way to use 'forloop counter' from 'for' with query?

Comment: What's the problem? What's not working?

Comment: @bdbd Nothing is printed out